# Spring boot 2.7.5 and Spring Security 6.0.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Can you deploy spring security latest version 6.0.2 to a project using spring boot 2.7.5 ? Does this cause incompatibility issues?

I want to implement spring security in a spring boot 2.7.5 project

Comment: 1. No. 2. Yes. Best: use the latest release (minor) version + according (managed) dependencies: https://start.spring.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be compatible as spring security only needs a Java 8 or higher Runtime Environment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).